# What is a line prall?

Tags: notation, ornaments

I am composing a melody for piano in Musescore, and after experimenting on a particular note with various ornaments (i.e. trills, mordents, etc.) I decided to use a 'line prall'. It sounded good, so I Googled it, hoping to find some information about it.

**Nothing.** Not a single relevant hit for "line prall", nor for "prall". Google has failed me.

What is a line prall (i.e. how does one play it) and are there any notable pieces in which at least one is featured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could that be another name for upper [mordent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordent)? Or [inverted mordent](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/music-glossary/ornament)?

> In music, a mordent is an ornament indicating that the note is to be played with a single rapid alternation with the note above or below. (wikipedia).

> The precise meaning of mordent has changed over the years. In the Baroque period, a mordent was a lower mordent and an upper mordent was a **pralltriller** or schneller.

#### Edit

Here is a portion of the source code of MuseScore (sorry :/), which tells you how MuseScore interprets ornamentation:

```
    //  articulation type            set of  duration       body         repeatp      suffix
//                               styles          prefix                    sustainp
{ SymId::ornamentTurn,                any, _32nd, {},    { 1,0,-1,0 },   false, true, {} },
{ SymId::ornamentTurnInverted,        any, _32nd, {},    { -1,0,1,0 },   false, true, {} },
{ SymId::ornamentTrill,           baroque, _32nd, { 1,0 }, { 1,0 },        true,  true, {} },
{ SymId::ornamentTrill,          defstyle, _32nd, { 0,1 }, { 0,1 },        true,  true, {} },
{ SymId::brassMuteClosed,         baroque, _32nd, { 0,-1 },{ 0, -1 },      true,  true, {} },
{ SymId::ornamentMordentInverted,     any, _32nd, {},    { 0,-1,0 },     false, true, {} },
{ SymId::ornamentMordent,        defstyle, _32nd, {},    { 0,1,0 },      false, true, {} },// inverted mordent
{ SymId::ornamentMordent,         baroque, _32nd, { 1,0,1 },{ 0 },         false, true, {} },// short trill
{ SymId::ornamentTremblement,         any, _32nd, { 1,0 }, { 1,0 },        false, true, {} },
{ SymId::ornamentPrallMordent,        any, _32nd, {},    { 1,0,-1,0 },   false, true, {} },
{ SymId::ornamentLinePrall,           any, _32nd, { 2,2,2 },{ 1,0 },       true,  true, {} },
{ SymId::ornamentUpPrall,             any, _16th, { -1,0 },{ 1,0 },        true,  true, { 1,0 } },// p 144 Ex 152 [1]
{ SymId::ornamentUpMordent,           any, _16th, { -1,0 },{ 1,0 },        true,  true, { -1,0 } }// p 144 Ex 152 [1]

,{ SymId::ornamentPrecompMordentUpperPrefix, any, _16th, { 1,1,1,0 }, { 1,0 },    true,  true, {} },// p136 Cadence Appuyee [1] [2]
{ SymId::ornamentDownMordent,         any, _16th, { 1,1,1,0 }, { 1,0 },    true,  true, { -1, 0 } },// p136 Cadence Appuyee + mordent [1] [2]
{ SymId::ornamentPrallUp,             any, _16th, { 1,0 }, { 1,0 },        true,  true, { -1,0 } },// p136 Double Cadence [1]
{ SymId::ornamentPrallDown,           any, _16th, { 1,0 }, { 1,0 },        true,  true, { -1,0,0,0 } },// p144 ex 153 [1]
{ SymId::ornamentPrecompSlide,        any, _32nd, {},    { 0 },          false, true, {} }

 // [1] Some of the articulations/ornaments in the excursions table above come from
// Baroque Music, Style and Performance A Handbook, by Robert Donington,(c) 1982
// ISBN 0-393-30052-8, W. W. Norton & Company, Inc.

// [2] In some cases, the example from [1] does not preserve the timing.
// For example, illustrates 2+1/4 counts per half note.
```

(rendermidi.cpp)

It has the same `body` as the trill which seems to indicate an excursion of 1 semi-tone up repeated, but I have to say I do not get the `prefix`/ `suffix` part, which are different… Wild guess: excursion of two semi-tones before for the line prall? Anyway, this is just MuseScore interpretation…

Comment: Found the correlation using DuckDuckGo ;)

Comment: Except Musescore has an up prall, a down prall, a prall prall, a line prall, and more. I would specifically like to know what a line prall is. Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: Isn't it another way of writing it?

Answer (score 4):

About three years too late for you, but this maybe helpful to others. I have found that pralls are really just the same thing as trill lines. Uppralls do a slide up into the trill notes, and the opposite for downpralls. A prallprall line is exactly the same as a trill line, except I don't think musescore has updated the sound, because all the pralls sound pretty bad in M4. As far as I can tell, it's like the difference between all the pedal lines. They might look different, but they do virtually the same thing.

Hope this helps!